# ModSecurity CRS, allow header `accept-charset`

Tags: waf, mod-security

I have ModSecurity v2 on apache with CRS v3.

Requests containing header [`accept-charset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept-Charset) are blocked on *paranoia level 1*, I read this great [discussion about the header](https://github.com/coreruleset/coreruleset/issues/3140) and that on CRS v4 will be allowed by default.

How can I write an exclusion rule to allow `accept-charset` header?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OWASP ModSecurity Core Rule Set Dev on Duty reporting. If you're working with a CRS v3 installation then you can configure CRS to allow the Accept-Charset header by removing it from the 'tx.restricted_headers' list in your `crs-setup.conf` file.

For CRS v4 we moved Accept-Charset to a new variable/list called 'tx.restricted_headers_extended'. This new list of headers is blocked at paranoia level 2, so if you use CRS v4 at PL2 or above then you would need to configure this list instead.

Comment: Could you perhaps tell us *how* to remove the header from 'tx.restricted_headers'?  What *specifically* do we need to put in crs-setup.conf?

Comment: @richard As above, it depends on whether you're using CRS v3 or v4. Assuming you're using v3, you would open your crs-setup.conf and find the section on 'restricted_headers'. Where the file says "Uncomment this rule to change the default", if you *don't* like the default setting then change it to whatever suits your deployment, and uncomment the rule. Now your custom setting will replace the default one. Be sure to reload or restart whatever services or containers are appropriate for your deployment, and you're good to go.